# Which is the best way to do a phased release package updates?

Tags: release-management, localrepository

I work on a company with multiple environments: dev, test, prod.

We currently have a way to test the updates posted on the Ubuntu Repositories but is really complex and doesn't work properly.

So we are trying to find a way that we can take a snapshot of the updates from the Ubuntu Repositories, then use the packages on that snapshot and only make them available to the dev servers.

After we update and make sure it doesn't break the dev servers we will like to make this snapshot available to the test servers, finally, if everything works properly do the same to the prod servers.

Aptly sounds like the right tool to do this, but since it uses a custom gpg key I can't do PXE/Netboot installation without allowing unauthenticated repositories or packages.

This is the line on the preseed file to allowing unauthenticated repositories or packages:

> d-i debian-installer/allow_unauthenticated boolean true

This is a deal breaker for us because its a security problem.

Being that said I'm looking for new options.

Thanks in advance!